# how do I reformat bib entries with a bst file so that a link is included?

Tags: bibtex, bst

I had to change a .bst file so that the following format.doi function is included:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { bbl.url url tie.or.space.connect output }
    { bbl.doi doi tie.or.space.connect output }
  if$
}
```

I want to change it so that "url" is accompanied by also printing a hyperref to the url, and DOI includes a link to doi by taking bbl.doi and adding the prefix https://doi.org/.

How is it possible to do that?

(I am aware the name format.doi is a bit misleading, it is a hack on the .bst file.)